# Use imports with string that comes from localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, local-storage

I need to show/hide different menu based on rights that are send from database and saved in localStorage.

Here is the imported menus

```
import tripOrders from './tripOrders';
import orders from './orders';
import employees from './employees';
```

Then I use them here:

```
const menuItems = {
    items: [tripOrders, orders, employees]
};
```

I tried to make something like this, but nothing happens.

```
let menuFromDB = localStorage.getItem('menu-items') // <== in 'menu-items' I set tripOrders, orders, employees

const menuItems = {
    items: [menuFromDB]
};
```

Comment: `localStorage` only stores `DOMString`s. add `console.log(menuFromDB)` before you try to use it to check

Comment: Ok, but can't i use it like a reference to the original import name ?

Comment: no, you have to store the items

Answer (score 0):

You get a string from localStorage, so you can use `split()` to convert it to the array

Comment: Hi, i convert it to array, but still don't call the imported files.